# How do I make the number of two-sided formulas in case_when depend on the number of arguments?

Tags: r, case, likert

I have two functions that I want to generalize below. I would like the generic function be called `likert_score`.

`a` is a vector of characters.
`length(a)` should be the number of two-sided formulas before the formula `TRUE ~ x`. How can I make this function or a reprex?

```
likert_score_4 <- function(x, a){
  a_seq <- seq_along(a) %>% as.character
  
  case_when(
    x == a[1] ~ a_seq[1],
    x == a[2] ~ a_seq[2],
    x == a[3] ~ a_seq[3],
    x == a[4] ~ a_seq[4],
    TRUE ~ x
  )
}


likert_score_5 <- function(x, a){
  case_when(
    x == a[1] ~ a_seq[1],
    x == a[2] ~ a_seq[2],
    x == a[3] ~ a_seq[3],
    x == a[4] ~ a_seq[4],
    x == a[5] ~ a_seq[5],
    TRUE ~ x
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
likert_score <- function(x, a){
   recode(x, !!!setNames(as.character(seq_along(a)), a))
}
```

Comment: this gives `1 15` and a warning message on my test example ...

Comment: I'm not sure: how does `case_when()` vectorize?  Maybe OP will clarify?

Comment: @BenBolker have made the necessary adjustments

Comment: can you explain what the `!!!` is doing?

Comment: @BenBolker its the Bang bang bang operator.

Comment: I know that's what it's called, I don't understand (remember) what it's doing.

Comment: @BenBolker in this case insteaof of having `recode(x, A=1, B-2, C=3)` i can have `recode(x, !!!named_vector)` I have little idea of how it works but similar to the `**` (not the power form) in python which uses the key word arguments

Comment: OK, so equivalent to `do.call(recode, c(list(x), as.list(setNames(...))))` in base R.

Comment: @BenBolker yes, the `do.call/invoke`. But I do not really know how the bang bang bang works

Comment: `!!!` injects a list of arguments. See https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rlang/html/splice-operator.html

Answer (score 2):

- `match(x,a)` finds the index of the matching element in `a` for each value of `x`, `NA` if there is no match
- the `ifelse()` replaces non-matching values with the corresponding values of `x` (could also say `x[!is.na(m)] <- na.omit(m)`)
- then we use `as.character()` in case we need it

```r
likert_score <- function(x,a ) {
  m <- match(x, a)
  as.character(ifelse(is.na(m), x, m))
}
```

```r
a <- LETTERS[1:4]
set.seed(101)
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 20, replace = TRUE)
identical(likert_score_4(x,a), likert_score(x,a))  ## TRUE
```

or if you want it inscrutable and pipe-y:

```r
match(x,a) %>% ifelse(test = is.na(.), yes = x) %>% as.character()
```