# How to build a sequence of two sided formulas from vectors

Tags: r

Consider two example dataframes in R

```
data.frame(data = sample(c(letters,LETTERS),10)) -> mydf
data.frame(lower = letters, upper = LETTERS) -> lookup
```

I want to replace the values in `mydf$data` with `lookup$upper` when `mydf$data` values match `lookup$lower`. The `case_match` in dplyr is well suited for this. However when the dataframes are large, it is not practical to write the sequences of two sided formulas by hand. From the  mention of dynamic dots in the documentation, I guess that it is possible to generate the list of two sided formulas by some kind of specification. However, I couldn't succeed.

My unsuccessful attempts were

```
case_match(mydf$data, !!!lookup$lower ~ !!!lookup$upper)
case_match(mydf$data, inject(!!!lookup$lower ~ !!!lookup$upper))
case_match(mydf$data, inject(!!!lookup$lower) ~ inject(!!!lookup$upper))
case_match(mydf$data, inject(!!lookup$lower) ~ inject(!!lookup$upper))
case_match(mydf$data, inject(!!lookup$lower ~ !!lookup$upper))
case_match(mydf$data, !!lookup$lower ~ !!lookup$upper))
```

and, of course,
`as.formula(paste(lookup$lower,  "~", lookup$upper, collapse = ", "))` 
fails too.

Is it possible to build a sequence of two sided formulas (as required for case_match) from vectors? If so, how? (I have seen [How do I make the number of two-sided formulas in case_when depend on the number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245673/how-do-i-make-the-number-of-two-sided-formulas-in-case-when-depend-on-the-number). But, recode needs a named vector and not two sided formulas.)

If not, how can I achieve the substitutions I want?

Thanks,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you could use `match` to create the indices (`ix`) then use `ifelse` - note I create `data2` just for comparison, but can overwrite `data` if desired:

```
ix <- match(mydf$data, lookup$lower)

mydf$data2 <- ifelse(!is.na(ix), lookup$upper[ix], mydf$data)

#    data data2
# 1     B     B
# 2     p     P
# 3     v     V
# 4     K     K
# 5     R     R
# 6     U     U
# 7     i     I
# 8     e     E
# 9     L     L
# 10    Y     Y
```

Reproducible Data:

```
set.seed(1234)
data.frame(data = sample(c(letters,LETTERS),10)) -> mydf
data.frame(lower = letters, upper = LETTERS) -> lookup
```

Comment: This is the better option to make the substitutions as it is faster than using injection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this as a join instead:

```
mydf |>
  left_join(lookup, by = c("data" = "lower")) |>
  mutate(data = coalesce(upper, data)) |>
  select(-upper)
#   data
# 1     M
# 2     P
# 3     B
# 4     D
# 5     N
# 6     V
# 7     H
# 8     X
# 9     O
# 10    T
```

Note that if you are updating **different columns** than you are joining on, the `rows_update()` function may make this even easier.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure this works. But, for me, this solution is a bit verbose than using match or even recode.

Comment: Yes, this is a more general solution that could work for multiple columns. But for a single column it is certainly more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

use the function `recode`

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>%
   mutate(data1 = recode(data, !!!deframe(lookup)))

   data data1
1     B     B
2     p     P
3     v     V
4     K     K
5     R     R
6     U     U
7     i     I
8     e     E
9     L     L
10    Y     Y
```

Comment: @GregorThomas you are right regarding the `str_replace` method.  Will delete that option

Comment: This suggestion works. However, from its documentation, recode() is superseded in favor of case_match().

Comment: @ajith Although superseded, you can still use it. eg its easier to use recode here than case_match. Otherwise use `fct_recode` which is not superseded and does the same thing with the caveat that you will have to reverse the frame ie `deframe(rev(df))` . Note that superseded just means its not being updated.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

## Usage

Per the documentation, using [`case_match()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html)...

```r
case_when(
  x %in% c("a", "b") ~ 1,
  x %in% "c"         ~ 2,
  x %in% c("d", "e") ~ 3
)
```

...is equivalent to using [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) like so:

```r
case_match(x,
  c("a", "b") ~ 1,
  "c"         ~ 2,
  c("d", "e") ~ 3
)
```

## Intent

**Unless I'm mistaken, you're using injection in an effort to create the following:**

```r
case_match(mydf$data,
  "a" ~ "A",
  "b" ~ "B",
  # ...
  "z" ~ "Z"
)
```

While this works, it is not exactly the intended use case for `case_match()`: you're not matching against *sets* of letters, but rather against *individual* letters.  You might as well create a `case_when()` like this:

```r
case_when(
  mydf$data == "a" ~ "A",
  mydf$data == "b" ~ "B",
  # ...
  mydf$data == "z" ~ "Z"
)
```

## Solutions

You're likely better off with [@GregorThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/u/903061)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043095) to [`*_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html), or with [@jpsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/u/12109788)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043162) to [`match()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/match.html).  However, here are solutions similar to your own approach.

### Setup

Ensure the data is reproducible, consistently with [@jpsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/u/12109788)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043162).

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)

data.frame(data = sample(c(letters,LETTERS),10)) -> mydf
data.frame(lower = letters, upper = LETTERS) -> lookup
```

### Injection in `case_match()`

Use [`rlang::new_formula()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/new_formula.html) to generate formulae like `"x" ~ "X"`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rlang)


# Generate list of formulae:
#   "a" ~ "A"
#   "b" ~ "B"
#   ...
#   "z" ~ "Z"
formulae_match <- map2(lookup$lower, lookup$upper, new_formula)


# Inject those formulae as arguments.
case_match(mydf$data,
  !!!formulae_match,
  .default = mydf$data
)
```

> ```
>  [1] "B" "P" "V" "K" "R" "U" "I" "E" "L" "Y"
> ```

### Injection in `case_when()`

Use [`rlang::call2()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/call2.html) to generate conditions like `mydf$data == "x"`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rlang)


# Capture the syntax for 'mydf$data' and '=='.
input <- rlang::expr(mydf$data)
operator <- rlang::expr(`==`)


# Generate a list of conditions:
#   mydf$data == "a"
#   mydf$data == "b"
#   ...
#   mydf$data == "z"
conditions <- map2(list(input), lookup$lower, call2, .fn = operator)


# Generate a list of formulae:
#   mydf$data == "a" ~ "A"
#   mydf$data == "b" ~ "B"
#   ...
#   mydf$data == "z" ~ "Z"
formulae_when <- map2(conditions, lookup$upper, new_formula)


# Inject those formulae as arguments.
case_when(
  !!!formulae_when,
  .default = mydf$data
)
```

> ```
>  [1] "B" "P" "V" "K" "R" "U" "I" "E" "L" "Y"
> ```

## Note

The performance is identical:

```r
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(times = 1000,
  match = case_match(mydf$data, !!!formulae_match, .default = mydf$data),
  when = case_when(!!!formulae_when, .default = mydf$data)
)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>   expr   min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
>  match 380.9 400.1 465.0785 415.30 440.85 3862.3  1000
>   when 381.3 398.0 453.5728 414.65 438.40 3481.0  1000
> ```

Comment: Yes, I was asking about injection. This does work and is the answer to my first question. Also it gives a valuable suggestion that I am better off with @jpsmith 's suggestion to use match.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to ask for new tags. No tags exist for injection, dynamic dots, case_when or case_match. May be there is a case for at least one of these tags.